# why is my $setting array variable not keeping its values?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem with the below:-

```
//index.php
<?php

define('PATH','Ajfit/');

/* Get all the required files and functions */
require(PATH . 'settings.inc.php');
require(PATH . 'inc/common.inc.php');

?>

//setting.inc.php
<?php
      $settings['language']='English';
?>

//inc/common.inc.php
<?php
      //global $settings, $lang, $_SESSION; //$setting = null????
      $language = $settings['language']; //$language is still null
?>
```

when i try and access the global variable $settings within common.inc.php it is set null even though i set the variable within setting.inc.php. If i debug, when i step out of setting.inc.php the $settings valiable is set within the index.php, however when i step into common.inc.php the $settings valiable is set to null.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Wait why would you use `global` here, you're already coding within the global scope

Comment: Exactly, you don't need the global keyword. `echo $settings['language'];` will print the correct value.

Comment: Please check when and how to use `global` : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: if i remove the global the code doe not compile as $settings is uninitizied in the common.inc.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer:** In the `inc/common.inc.php` file, you don't need to use the `global` keyword, the variable is already accessible. Using `global` redefines the variable, and is thus made `null`.

**Explanation:**

*Variable Scope* is the key here. The `global` keyword is only required when scope changes. The scope of regular files (including `include()`s) is all the same, so all of your variables are accessible by any php in the same scope, even if it comes from a different file.

An example of where you need to use `global` is inside of functions. The scope of a function is different than that of plain php, which is different from `class` scope, and so on.

**Example:**

```
//foo.php
  $foo = "bar";

  echo $foo; //prints "bar" since scope hasn't changed.

  function zoo() {
    echo $foo; //prints "" because of scope change.
  }

  function zoo2() {
    global $foo;
    echo $foo; //prints "bar" because $foo is recognized as in a higher scope.
  }

  include('bar.php');

//bar.php
  echo $foo; //prints "bar" because scope still hasn't changed.

  function zoo3() {
    echo $foo; //prints "" for the same reason as in zoo()
  }

  function zoo4() {
    global $foo;
    echo $foo; //prints "bar" for the same reason as in zoo2()
  }
```

**More Information:**

If you want more information on when to use `global` and when not to, check the [php.net documentation on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: OK, i understand but i have removed the global line completely out of the common.inc.php and replaced it with $language = $settings['language']; however, $language is still null and the $settings is also null.

Comment: try initializing the array with `$settings = array(); $settings['language'] = 'English';`

Comment: That did not help, the funny thing is when i step out of settings.inc.php the $settings IS populated, then when i step into inc/common.inc.php the $setting variable is null. Its like its lost its scope.